# Computing the infimum in convex optimization

Tags: normed-spaces, convex-optimization, supremum-and-infimum

I am studying optimization from Boyd's book "Convex optimization". In problem 4.25, Linear separation of two sets of ellipsoids, with some hints I concluded that we have the inequalities $\inf_{\|u\|_2 \leq 1} a^TP_i u + a^Tq_i \geq 1$ and $\sup_{\|u\|_2 \leq 1}a^TP_iu + a^Tq_i \leq -1$. Then the solutions say that $\inf_{\|u\|_2 \leq 1} (a^TP_i u + a^Tq_i + b) = -\|a^TP_i\|_2 + a^Tq_i + b$ and $\sup_{\|u\|_2 \leq 1} (a^TP_i u + a^Tq_i + b) = \|a^TP_i\|_2 + a^Tq_i + b$. I am struggling to understand how we got these equalities. Particularly, how did we conclude that $\inf_{\|u\|_2 \leq 1} (a^TP_i u) = -\|a^TP_i\|_2$ and $\sup{\|u\|_2 \leq 1} (a^TP_i u) = \|a^TP_i\|_2$. Can anyone help me understand how this happens?? Thanks!

Comment: You must have a mistake with the first two inequalities.

Comment: In general, we have $\min_{\|u\|_2  \le 1} \langle u, x \rangle = -\|x\|_2$ and similarly for $\max$.  It follows from the Cauchy Schwarz inequality and conditions for equality thereof.

Comment: I see, but then I'm not so sure where did you get the $\langle u, x \rangle$ expression?

Comment: Nevermind, I completely understan why this happens now. Thanks!